# Cannot Access Network based location when location access is off

Tags: android, gps, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am using google location api for fetching location. issue I'm facing is when the user turned the GPS off I'm not getting the Lcoation, as per [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40383/can-apps-know-where-you-are-even-without-gps) post says we can access Network based location even-though the GPS is turned off. but I'm not getting locaton when the user turned off the location access.

this is my service to fetch location

```
public class LocationUpdateService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, ResultCallback<Status> {


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    startLocationUpdates();
    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LogUtils.LOGI(TAG, "Service created");
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    setupBroadCastListenerForGpsStatusChange();
    initLastLocationDetails();
}


/**
 * Requests location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
 */
protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    } else {
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}

/**
 * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the {@code #addApi} method to request the
 * LocationServices API.
 */
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    LogUtils.LOGI(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(SMALLEST_DISTANCE_METERS);
}

  @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

   @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      //location operations 
   }     
}
```

So my question is, Is it really possible to access location when the location access is disabled (*not last cached location*), if yes, what is wrong with my code

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (isNetworkEnabled) {
   manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BTWN_UPDATES,
                            DISTANCE_OF_UPDAPTES, this);
     if (manager != null) {
     location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
       if (location != null) {
          latitude = location.getLatitude();
          longitude = location.getLongitude();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: please read the question carefully before answering, see I'm using google play location api, and you are posting answer for android native location api

Answer (score 0):

You canot start the service natively using just Google Api Location , you should manage to operate the location based on user request by using boolean location manager. Otherwise your attempts dose not look superficial,  you can either use **get** when **gps** is **on** or **off** depending when detected.

Comment: i dint unserstand, can you explain more ?

Comment: Follow patel milan answer , this should guide you for further explanation , your code attributes attempt to authenticate a Google Based API request!! Based on! You have to define what to request and whom request to whom , and that is achievable by identifying location manager and location based on permission.